# duplicate terms added by taxonomy_term_save

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Doesn't taxonomy_term_save() check if terms are being added in duplicate ? I have the following code -

```
function custom_create_taxonomy_term($name, $vid) {
  $term = new stdClass();
  $term->name = $name;
  $term->vid = $vid;
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
  return $term->tid;
}
```

But whenever I pass it a $name- which already exists in that vocabulary, then also a new entry is made in the database and there are 2 tids for the same term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly ok to have terms with the same name in the same vocabulary, the name column is not unique in the taxonomy_term_data table, and `taxonomy_term_save()` doesn't contain any logic to check.

This is by design as it would be very restrictive otherwise. Imagine you had a hierarchical vocab with many different levels...what happens if two terms happen to have the same name but live under different parents?

If you need your term names to be unique for whatever reason you can check if the term exists before saving it by using [`taxonomy_get_term_by_name()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7)

Comment: @Clive- hmm.. ya right, i got your point. It was just that it seemed a bit fishy u know, the idea of a primary key is that it should identify each row/entry uniquely, which is not being done in this case. I understood it now, why it isn't so. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the hierarchical vocab the check still could be done by having the combination of the parent->child combination is always unique and hence avoid the duplicates.

The top level terms would have its parents as empty and subsequently we could avoid this bug.

Check out [Taxonomy dupecheck](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_dupecheck):

> Taxonomy dupecheck module prevents Drupal administrators from adding
>   duplicate taxonomy vocabularies and/or terms. It's helpful when
>   entering large amounts of terms or vocabularies in situations where
>   each value must be unique. This saves time by preventing
>   administrators from having to enforce a unique value policy through
>   later cleanup of duplicate terms.